# Sending message from iOS app to tv iOS + SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

Please tell me how can I send messages from an iphone app to an apple tv programatically.

Is there any api for that?
I have searched but have not found any proper solution. Can someone help me out on this?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is no Api for communicating that way with the AppleTV